# dsregcmd on windows server core

Tags: windows, windows-server-core

I have installed windows server core 2022 (standard) and successfully joined it to a domain as a member server.

I'm now trying to use `dsregcmd /status` to show the domain join status.

For some reason, the `C:\Windows\system32\dsregcmd.exe` binary is missing on this server.

Is it normal that `dsregcmd` is not available on this edition of windows server?

I have checked and can confirm that it is present on the non-core edition of windows server 2022.

Comment: Good find. Can't speak to "normal", but given what else isn't available probably not unexpected. Maybe nltest would be an alternative.